# File Path Auto Complete in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm taking file path as input from user in tkinter text widget , those file paths are usually long so I want to allow auto completion of the file path when "Tab" is pressed. I tried it in python script and it worked :

```
    readline.set_completer_delims(' \t\n')
    readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")
    my_file=input("\nPlease Enter The Path to  File: ").replace(" ","")
    while not (os.path.exists(my_file)):
          my_file=input("\nPlease Enter The Path to File: ").replace(" ","")
```

I'm trying to do the same in tkinter but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Text



root = Tk()


text_widget = Text(root)

def enter():
    data = text_widget.get("1.0","end")
    " Your Code "
    print(data)

button = Button(root,text="Ok",command=enter)

text_widget.pack()
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You are missing `root.mainloop()`. Also wouldn't it be better if instead of `entry`, you used `text` as the variable name? Also you should pass in `root` as the first argument for both `Text()` and `Button(...)`. And `from ... import *` is discouraged.

Comment: I just gived a example and I didn't pay attention to make the code awesome. But I edited.